# SQL: find continuous date ranges across multiple rows?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to get a start and end date combination for continuous spans of time worked. The spans can cross multiple rows, where the end date of the first row is the same as the end date of the next row. The intended result is to show a continuous date range with the sum of hours worked for that range.

```
person  startdate                enddate                   hours
------  -----------------------  -----------------------  ------
5163    2013-04-29 07:00:00.000  2013-04-29 11:00:00.000    4.00
5163    2013-04-29 11:30:00.000  2013-04-29 15:30:00.000    4.00
5163    2013-04-29 15:30:00.000  2013-04-29 19:06:00.000    3.60
5851    2013-05-02 19:00:00.000  2013-05-02 23:00:00.000    4.00
5851    2013-05-02 23:00:00.000  2013-05-03 00:00:00.000    1.00
5851    2013-05-03 00:00:00.000  2013-05-03 00:31:00.000    0.52
```

From the above data, I want the following.

```
person  startdate                enddate                   hours
------  -----------------------  -----------------------  ------
5163    2013-04-29 07:00:00.000  2013-04-29 11:00:00.000    4.00
5163    2013-04-29 11:30:00.000  2013-04-29 19:06:00.000    7.60
5851    2013-05-02 19:00:00.000  2013-05-03 00:31:00.000    5.52
```

For each person and new (non-continuous) date span, compare the current row's enddate to the next row's startdate. If they are the same, accumulate the hours and continue processing rows until the enddate / startdate does not equal.

The environment is SQL Server 2008 R2. I tried queries involving self joins, using row_number and partition() functions, but have not been able to get a successful solution. Thanks!

edit: Here is the data flow for RichardTheKiwi's solution - I ran it for one person to see how much recursion is generated for a week's worth of punches.

```
declare @startdate datetime;
    set @startdate = '20130429';
declare @enddate datetime;
    set @enddate = '20130506';

with tbl as (
select 
PERSONNUM,
STARTDTM,
ENDDTM,
convert(decimal(10,2),1.0 * TIMEINSECONDS / 3600) as timeinhours
from vp_totals
where paycodetype = 'p'
and applydate >= @startdate and APPLYDATE < @enddate 
and (paycodename like '%regular%'
     or paycodename like '%overtime%'
     or PAYCODENAME like '%double time%')
and (PAYCODENAME not like '%shift premium%')
and PERSONNUM = 'loh-5851'
)

select * from tbl order by startdtm -- 27 rows


PERSONNUM       STARTDTM            ENDDTM               timeinhours 
LOH-5851        2013-04-29 14:30:00 2013-04-29 18:30:00  4.0000 
LOH-5851        2013-04-29 19:00:00 2013-04-29 23:00:00  4.0000 
LOH-5851        2013-04-29 23:00:00 2013-04-30 00:00:00  1.0000 
LOH-5851        2013-04-30 00:00:00 2013-04-30 00:11:00  0.1800 
LOH-5851        2013-04-30 14:45:00 2013-04-30 18:45:00  4.0000 
LOH-5851        2013-04-30 19:15:00 2013-04-30 23:00:00  3.7500 
LOH-5851        2013-04-30 23:00:00 2013-04-30 23:15:00  0.2500 
LOH-5851        2013-04-30 23:15:00 2013-05-01 00:00:00  0.7500 
LOH-5851        2013-05-01 00:00:00 2013-05-01 00:11:00  0.1800 
LOH-5851        2013-05-01 14:30:00 2013-05-01 18:30:00  4.0000 
LOH-5851        2013-05-01 19:00:00 2013-05-01 23:00:00  4.0000 
LOH-5851        2013-05-01 23:00:00 2013-05-02 00:00:00  1.0000 
LOH-5851        2013-05-02 00:00:00 2013-05-02 00:22:00  0.3700 
LOH-5851        2013-05-02 14:30:00 2013-05-02 18:30:00  4.0000 
LOH-5851        2013-05-02 19:00:00 2013-05-02 23:00:00  4.0000 
LOH-5851        2013-05-02 23:00:00 2013-05-03 00:00:00  1.0000 
LOH-5851        2013-05-03 00:00:00 2013-05-03 00:31:00  0.5200 
LOH-5851        2013-05-03 14:45:00 2013-05-03 17:45:00  3.0000 
LOH-5851        2013-05-03 17:45:00 2013-05-03 18:45:00  1.0000 
LOH-5851        2013-05-03 19:15:00 2013-05-03 23:00:00  3.7500 
LOH-5851        2013-05-03 23:00:00 2013-05-03 23:15:00  0.2500 
LOH-5851        2013-05-03 23:15:00 2013-05-04 00:00:00  0.7500 
LOH-5851        2013-05-04 00:00:00 2013-05-04 00:15:00  0.2500 
LOH-5851        2013-05-04 14:00:00 2013-05-04 18:00:00  4.0000 
LOH-5851        2013-05-04 18:30:00 2013-05-04 22:30:00  4.0000 
LOH-5851        2013-05-04 22:30:00 2013-05-04 23:00:00  0.5000 
LOH-5851        2013-05-04 23:00:00 2013-05-04 23:30:00  0.5000 


,cte as (
    select personnum, startdtm, enddtm, timeinhours
    from tbl
    union all
    select t.personnum, cte.startdtm, t.enddtm, cast(cte.timeinhours + t.timeinhours as decimal(10,2))
    from cte
    join tbl t on cte.personnum = t.personnum and cte.enddtm = t.startdtm
)

select * from cte order by startdtm, timeinhours option (maxrecursion 32000) -- 52 rows



personnum       startdtm            enddtm               timeinhours 
LOH-5851        2013-04-29 14:30:00 2013-04-29 18:30:00  4.0000 
LOH-5851        2013-04-29 19:00:00 2013-04-29 23:00:00  4.0000 
LOH-5851        2013-04-29 19:00:00 2013-04-30 00:00:00  5.0000 
LOH-5851        2013-04-29 19:00:00 2013-04-30 00:11:00  5.1800 
LOH-5851        2013-04-29 23:00:00 2013-04-30 00:00:00  1.0000 
LOH-5851        2013-04-29 23:00:00 2013-04-30 00:11:00  1.1800 
LOH-5851        2013-04-30 00:00:00 2013-04-30 00:11:00  0.1800 
LOH-5851        2013-04-30 14:45:00 2013-04-30 18:45:00  4.0000 
LOH-5851        2013-04-30 19:15:00 2013-04-30 23:00:00  3.7500 
LOH-5851        2013-04-30 19:15:00 2013-04-30 23:15:00  4.0000 
LOH-5851        2013-04-30 19:15:00 2013-05-01 00:00:00  4.7500 
LOH-5851        2013-04-30 19:15:00 2013-05-01 00:11:00  4.9300 
LOH-5851        2013-04-30 23:00:00 2013-04-30 23:15:00  0.2500 
LOH-5851        2013-04-30 23:00:00 2013-05-01 00:00:00  1.0000 
LOH-5851        2013-04-30 23:00:00 2013-05-01 00:11:00  1.1800 
LOH-5851        2013-04-30 23:15:00 2013-05-01 00:00:00  0.7500 
LOH-5851        2013-04-30 23:15:00 2013-05-01 00:11:00  0.9300 
LOH-5851        2013-05-01 00:00:00 2013-05-01 00:11:00  0.1800 
LOH-5851        2013-05-01 14:30:00 2013-05-01 18:30:00  4.0000 
LOH-5851        2013-05-01 19:00:00 2013-05-01 23:00:00  4.0000 
LOH-5851        2013-05-01 19:00:00 2013-05-02 00:00:00  5.0000 
LOH-5851        2013-05-01 19:00:00 2013-05-02 00:22:00  5.3700 
LOH-5851        2013-05-01 23:00:00 2013-05-02 00:00:00  1.0000 
LOH-5851        2013-05-01 23:00:00 2013-05-02 00:22:00  1.3700 
LOH-5851        2013-05-02 00:00:00 2013-05-02 00:22:00  0.3700 
LOH-5851        2013-05-02 14:30:00 2013-05-02 18:30:00  4.0000 
LOH-5851        2013-05-02 19:00:00 2013-05-02 23:00:00  4.0000 
LOH-5851        2013-05-02 19:00:00 2013-05-03 00:00:00  5.0000 
LOH-5851        2013-05-02 19:00:00 2013-05-03 00:31:00  5.5200 
LOH-5851        2013-05-02 23:00:00 2013-05-03 00:00:00  1.0000 
LOH-5851        2013-05-02 23:00:00 2013-05-03 00:31:00  1.5200 
LOH-5851        2013-05-03 00:00:00 2013-05-03 00:31:00  0.5200 
LOH-5851        2013-05-03 14:45:00 2013-05-03 17:45:00  3.0000 
LOH-5851        2013-05-03 14:45:00 2013-05-03 18:45:00  4.0000 
LOH-5851        2013-05-03 17:45:00 2013-05-03 18:45:00  1.0000 
LOH-5851        2013-05-03 19:15:00 2013-05-03 23:00:00  3.7500 
LOH-5851        2013-05-03 19:15:00 2013-05-03 23:15:00  4.0000 
LOH-5851        2013-05-03 19:15:00 2013-05-04 00:00:00  4.7500 
LOH-5851        2013-05-03 19:15:00 2013-05-04 00:15:00  5.0000 
LOH-5851        2013-05-03 23:00:00 2013-05-03 23:15:00  0.2500 
LOH-5851        2013-05-03 23:00:00 2013-05-04 00:00:00  1.0000 
LOH-5851        2013-05-03 23:00:00 2013-05-04 00:15:00  1.2500 
LOH-5851        2013-05-03 23:15:00 2013-05-04 00:00:00  0.7500 
LOH-5851        2013-05-03 23:15:00 2013-05-04 00:15:00  1.0000 
LOH-5851        2013-05-04 00:00:00 2013-05-04 00:15:00  0.2500 
LOH-5851        2013-05-04 14:00:00 2013-05-04 18:00:00  4.0000 
LOH-5851        2013-05-04 18:30:00 2013-05-04 22:30:00  4.0000 
LOH-5851        2013-05-04 18:30:00 2013-05-04 23:00:00  4.5000 
LOH-5851        2013-05-04 18:30:00 2013-05-04 23:30:00  5.0000 
LOH-5851        2013-05-04 22:30:00 2013-05-04 23:00:00  0.5000 
LOH-5851        2013-05-04 22:30:00 2013-05-04 23:30:00  1.0000 
LOH-5851        2013-05-04 23:00:00 2013-05-04 23:30:00  0.5000 



,cte2 as (
    select *, rn = row_number() over (partition by personnum, enddtm order by startdtm)
    from cte
)

select * from cte2 order by startdtm, rn -- 52 rows


personnum       startdtm            enddtm               timeinhours        rn
LOH-5851        2013-04-29 14:30:00 2013-04-29 18:30:00  4.0000             1
LOH-5851        2013-04-29 19:00:00 2013-04-29 23:00:00  4.0000             1
LOH-5851        2013-04-29 19:00:00 2013-04-30 00:00:00  5.0000             1
LOH-5851        2013-04-29 19:00:00 2013-04-30 00:11:00  5.1800             1
LOH-5851        2013-04-29 23:00:00 2013-04-30 00:11:00  1.1800             2
LOH-5851        2013-04-29 23:00:00 2013-04-30 00:00:00  1.0000             2
LOH-5851        2013-04-30 00:00:00 2013-04-30 00:11:00  0.1800             3
LOH-5851        2013-04-30 14:45:00 2013-04-30 18:45:00  4.0000             1
LOH-5851        2013-04-30 19:15:00 2013-04-30 23:00:00  3.7500             1
LOH-5851        2013-04-30 19:15:00 2013-04-30 23:15:00  4.0000             1
LOH-5851        2013-04-30 19:15:00 2013-05-01 00:11:00  4.9300             1
LOH-5851        2013-04-30 19:15:00 2013-05-01 00:00:00  4.7500             1
LOH-5851        2013-04-30 23:00:00 2013-05-01 00:00:00  1.0000             2
LOH-5851        2013-04-30 23:00:00 2013-05-01 00:11:00  1.1800             2
LOH-5851        2013-04-30 23:00:00 2013-04-30 23:15:00  0.2500             2
LOH-5851        2013-04-30 23:15:00 2013-05-01 00:11:00  0.9300             3
LOH-5851        2013-04-30 23:15:00 2013-05-01 00:00:00  0.7500             3
LOH-5851        2013-05-01 00:00:00 2013-05-01 00:11:00  0.1800             4
LOH-5851        2013-05-01 14:30:00 2013-05-01 18:30:00  4.0000             1
LOH-5851        2013-05-01 19:00:00 2013-05-01 23:00:00  4.0000             1
LOH-5851        2013-05-01 19:00:00 2013-05-02 00:00:00  5.0000             1
LOH-5851        2013-05-01 19:00:00 2013-05-02 00:22:00  5.3700             1
LOH-5851        2013-05-01 23:00:00 2013-05-02 00:22:00  1.3700             2
LOH-5851        2013-05-01 23:00:00 2013-05-02 00:00:00  1.0000             2
LOH-5851        2013-05-02 00:00:00 2013-05-02 00:22:00  0.3700             3
LOH-5851        2013-05-02 14:30:00 2013-05-02 18:30:00  4.0000             1
LOH-5851        2013-05-02 19:00:00 2013-05-02 23:00:00  4.0000             1
LOH-5851        2013-05-02 19:00:00 2013-05-03 00:00:00  5.0000             1
LOH-5851        2013-05-02 19:00:00 2013-05-03 00:31:00  5.5200             1
LOH-5851        2013-05-02 23:00:00 2013-05-03 00:31:00  1.5200             2
LOH-5851        2013-05-02 23:00:00 2013-05-03 00:00:00  1.0000             2
LOH-5851        2013-05-03 00:00:00 2013-05-03 00:31:00  0.5200             3
LOH-5851        2013-05-03 14:45:00 2013-05-03 17:45:00  3.0000             1
LOH-5851        2013-05-03 14:45:00 2013-05-03 18:45:00  4.0000             1
LOH-5851        2013-05-03 17:45:00 2013-05-03 18:45:00  1.0000             2
LOH-5851        2013-05-03 19:15:00 2013-05-03 23:00:00  3.7500             1
LOH-5851        2013-05-03 19:15:00 2013-05-03 23:15:00  4.0000             1
LOH-5851        2013-05-03 19:15:00 2013-05-04 00:00:00  4.7500             1
LOH-5851        2013-05-03 19:15:00 2013-05-04 00:15:00  5.0000             1
LOH-5851        2013-05-03 23:00:00 2013-05-04 00:15:00  1.2500             2
LOH-5851        2013-05-03 23:00:00 2013-05-04 00:00:00  1.0000             2
LOH-5851        2013-05-03 23:00:00 2013-05-03 23:15:00  0.2500             2
LOH-5851        2013-05-03 23:15:00 2013-05-04 00:00:00  0.7500             3
LOH-5851        2013-05-03 23:15:00 2013-05-04 00:15:00  1.0000             3
LOH-5851        2013-05-04 00:00:00 2013-05-04 00:15:00  0.2500             4
LOH-5851        2013-05-04 14:00:00 2013-05-04 18:00:00  4.0000             1
LOH-5851        2013-05-04 18:30:00 2013-05-04 22:30:00  4.0000             1
LOH-5851        2013-05-04 18:30:00 2013-05-04 23:00:00  4.5000             1
LOH-5851        2013-05-04 18:30:00 2013-05-04 23:30:00  5.0000             1
LOH-5851        2013-05-04 22:30:00 2013-05-04 23:30:00  1.0000             2
LOH-5851        2013-05-04 22:30:00 2013-05-04 23:00:00  0.5000             2
LOH-5851        2013-05-04 23:00:00 2013-05-04 23:30:00  0.5000             3


select personnum, startdtm, max(enddtm) enddtm, max(timeinhours) timeinhours
from cte2
where rn=1
group by personnum, startdtm
order by personnum, startdtm
option (maxrecursion 32000) -- 12 rows


personnum       startdtm            enddtm               timeinhours 
LOH-5851        2013-04-29 14:30:00 2013-04-29 18:30:00  4.0000 
LOH-5851        2013-04-29 19:00:00 2013-04-30 00:11:00  5.1800 
LOH-5851        2013-04-30 14:45:00 2013-04-30 18:45:00  4.0000 
LOH-5851        2013-04-30 19:15:00 2013-05-01 00:11:00  4.9300 
LOH-5851        2013-05-01 14:30:00 2013-05-01 18:30:00  4.0000 
LOH-5851        2013-05-01 19:00:00 2013-05-02 00:22:00  5.3700 
LOH-5851        2013-05-02 14:30:00 2013-05-02 18:30:00  4.0000 
LOH-5851        2013-05-02 19:00:00 2013-05-03 00:31:00  5.5200 
LOH-5851        2013-05-03 14:45:00 2013-05-03 18:45:00  4.0000 
LOH-5851        2013-05-03 19:15:00 2013-05-04 00:15:00  5.0000 
LOH-5851        2013-05-04 14:00:00 2013-05-04 18:00:00  4.0000 
LOH-5851        2013-05-04 18:30:00 2013-05-04 23:30:00  5.0000
```

The query works perfectly for small amounts of data, but when run for the expected employee population for a pay period (usually one week), the ugly max recursions error message appears.

edit edit: see the comments for Richard's fix for the recursion issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sample data

```
create table tbl (person int, startdate datetime, enddate datetime, hours decimal(10,2));
insert tbl values
(5163 ,'2013-04-29 07:00:00.000' ,'2013-04-29 11:00:00.000', 4.00),
(5163 ,'2013-04-29 11:30:00.000' ,'2013-04-29 15:30:00.000', 4.00),
(5163 ,'2013-04-29 15:30:00.000' ,'2013-04-29 19:06:00.000', 3.60),
(5851 ,'2013-05-02 19:00:00.000' ,'2013-05-02 23:00:00.000', 4.00),
(5851 ,'2013-05-02 23:00:00.000' ,'2013-05-03 00:00:00.000', 1.00),
(5851 ,'2013-05-03 00:00:00.000' ,'2013-05-03 00:31:00.000', 0.52);
```

The query

```
;with cte as (
    select person, startdate, enddate, hours
    from tbl
    union all
    select t.person, cte.startdate, t.enddate, cast(cte.hours + t.hours as decimal(10,2))
    from cte
    join tbl t on cte.person = t.person and cte.enddate = t.startdate
), cte2 as (
    select *, rn = row_number() over (partition by person, enddate order by startdate)
    from cte
)
select person, startdate, max(enddate) enddate, max(hours) hours
from cte2
where rn=1
group by person, startdate
order by person, startdate;
```

Results

```
person      startdate               enddate                 hours
----------- ----------------------- ----------------------- -------
5163        2013-04-29 07:00:00.000 2013-04-29 11:00:00.000 4.00
5163        2013-04-29 11:30:00.000 2013-04-29 19:06:00.000 7.60
5851        2013-05-02 19:00:00.000 2013-05-03 00:31:00.000 5.52
```

Comment: Hi Richard, thank you for this solution! I want to mark this as answered.... While it does work with the sample data provided, when run over production data, I get the error "The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.". Even received the error after using the hint "option (maxrecursion 32000)". The production data is about 600 rows, and I expect up to 1,500 rows for the query. Is there an alternative method that works around the recursion issue?

Comment: I think you have some record where the end date = start date. This is the only thing I can think of (at the moment) that would cause infinite recursion. You can prevent this using `from cte join tbl t on cte.person = t.person and cte.enddate = t.startdate and t.enddate != t.startdate`

Comment: Thanks again, Richard! The proposed change looks to fix the recursion problem and the output for my sample person looks correct.

Comment: Updated CTE section is:
;with cte as (
    select person, startdate, enddate, hours
    from tbl
    union all
    select t.person, cte.startdate, t.enddate, cast(cte.hours + t.hours as decimal(10,2))
    from cte
    join tbl t on cte.person = t.person and cte.enddate = t.startdate and t.enddate != t.startdate

Comment: How would you handle cases when the EndDate is not inclusive?  In other words, periods 1/1/2015 - 2/1/2015 and 2/2/2015 - 3/1/2015 should also be considered continuous.