# How to find contiguous dates in numerous rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a table with service provisions for people. For example:

```
id  people_id  dateStart   dateEnd
1   1          28.07.14    19.07.16
2   2          14.04.15    16.02.16
3   2          16.02.16    18.04.16
4   2          18.04.16    27.06.16
5   2          27.06.16    19.07.16
6   2          19.07.16    NULL
7   3          24.02.12    17.06.12
8   3          23.07.12    19.09.12
9   3          18.08.14    NULL
10  4          28.06.15    NULL
11  5          19.01.16    NULL
```

I need to extract distinct people_id's (clients) with real start date of unfinished uninterrupted service that lasts more than year and then count days pass. 'Start date' and 'End date' of two different rows should be the same to be count as contiguous. One client can only have one unfinished service.
So the perfect result for the table above would be:

```
people_id  dateStart   lasts(days)
2          14.04.15    472
3          18.08.14    711
4          28.06.15    397
```

I didn't have problem with a single service:

```
SELECT
    --some other columns from PEOPLE,
    p.PEOPLE_ID,
    s.DATESTART,
    DATEDIFF(DAY, s.DATESTART, GETDATE()) as lasts
FROM
    PEOPLE p
    INNER JOIN service s on s.ID =
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 s2.ID
        FROM service s2
        WHERE s2.PEOPLE_ID = p.PEOPLE_ID
            AND s2.DATESTART IS NOT NULL
            AND s2.DATEEND IS NULL
        ORDER BY s2.DATESTART DESC
    )
WHERE
    DATEDIFF(DAY, s.DATESTART , GETDATE()) >= 365
```

But I can't figure out how to determine contiguous services.

Comment: If `dateEnd` is `null`, does that mean it's ongoing?

Comment: @AshwinNair Yes it is. I need only active clients. If someone doesn't have any service with `dateEnd=NULL` he is **not** active.

Comment: what version of `SQL Server` are you using ?

Comment: @Squirrel `SQL Server 2012`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL: find continuous date ranges across multiple rows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16595993/sql-find-continuous-date-ranges-across-multiple-rows)

Comment: How quickly people have forgotten the lessons of Y2K!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find where periods of "continuous" service begin by using `lag()`.  Then a cumulative sum of this flag provides a group, which can be used for aggregation:

```
select people_id, min(datestart) as datestart,
       (case when count(dateend) = count(*) then max(dateend) end) as dateend
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_dateend = datestart then 0 else 1 end) over
                 (partition by people_id order by datestart) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(dateend) over (partition by people_id order by date_start) as prev_dateend
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by people_id, grp
having count(*) > count(dateend);
```

Comment: This query doesn't seem to be getting the number of days the OP requires (the `lasts(days)` column).

Comment: OP just need to use DATEDIFF() to get the days

Comment: so you agree it's not complete as well then : ). I was curious and tried out this query and I get 4 rows instead of 3 so the OP needs to add the check for `>=365`. Also, I'm getting `NULL` for all rows under the `dateend` column.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
select PeopleId, min(dateStart) as dateStart, sum(diff) as [lasts(days)] from 
(
    select P.*, datediff(day,datestart, DateEnd) as diff from
        (select  peopleId, dateStart,  
        isnull(dateend, cast(getdate() as date)) as DateEnd
        from People 
        ) P 
    where Dateend in 
        (select DateStart from People 
            where PeopleId = P.PeopleId) 
            or DateEnd = cast(getdate() as date ) -- check for continuous dates
) P1 group by PeopleId  having sum(diff)> 365       --check for > one year
```

The comments in the query should explain things

Comment: Thank you. In general you were right but forgot one another clause. Client should have at least one row where `DateEnd IS NULL` (i.e. active). So I added that clause and all seems alright now.

Comment: Glad to have helped.